# How to set up WiFi on Raspbian 4.4.13

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, wifi

Is there a new way to configure WiFi on Raspbian because since I upgraded to 4.4.13, my pi's WiFi broke.

```
pi@Y3moP1:~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
  wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

If I don't get that warning then it's something like 'Interface is busy'!

I had a perfectly functioning raspberry pi 2 until I upgraded the **firmware to 4.4.13-v7+**.

```
pi@Y3moP1:~ $ uname -r
  4.4.13-v7+
```

After that WiFi stopped working. Actually, the interface wlan0 won't go up. I didn't update the **/etc/network/interfaces** given that the warning in the header discourages to do so. So here is what I have:

```
pi@Y3moP1:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
  # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

  # Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
  # For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

  # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
  source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  iface eth0 inet manual

  allow-hotplug wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

  allow-hotplug wlan1
  iface wlan1 inet manual
      wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

However, I **updated my wpa_supplicant.conf** to include 2 WiFi networks - both unencrypted, one hidden - for testing purposes.

```
pi@Y3moP1:~ $ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 
  country=TG
  ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
  update_config=1

  network={
      ssid="R3B3LZ"
      scan_ssid=1
      key_mgmt=NONE
  }

  network={
      ssid="dd-wrt"
      key_mgmt=NONE
  }
```

First off, I am using a Ralink RT5370, and it is being picked up.

```
pi@Y3moP1:~ $ lsusb
  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Second, all the drivers seem to be up and loaded. At least the ones Ralink wifi devices require.

```
pi@Y3moP1:~ $ lsmod
  Module                  Size  Used by
  bnep                   10340  2 
  bluetooth             326105  5 bnep
  arc4                    1958  2 
  rt2800usb              17554  0 
  rt2800lib              71894  1 rt2800usb
  rt2x00usb               8943  1 rt2800usb
  rt2x00lib              37529  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
  mac80211              532034  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
  cfg80211              427855  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
  crc_ccitt               1278  1 rt2800lib
  rfkill                 16037  4 cfg80211,bluetooth
  snd_bcm2835            20511  1 
  snd_pcm                75698  1 snd_bcm2835
  snd_timer              19160  1 snd_pcm
  snd                    51844  5 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
  bcm2835_gpiomem         3040  0 
  bcm2835_wdt             3225  0 
  uio_pdrv_genirq         3164  0 
  uio                     8000  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
  i2c_dev                 5859  0 
  fuse                   83461  3 
  ipv6                  347530  46
```

Third, here's what I get when I run ifconfig -a

```
pi@Y3moP1:~ $ sudo ifconfig -a
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:bc:26:83  
        inet addr:192.168.1.145  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: fe80::fb39:efaf:b2bf:2a4a/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:2937 errors:0 dropped:7 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:2186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:199598 (194.9 KiB)  TX bytes:276407 (269.9 KiB)

  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
        RX bytes:20740 (20.2 KiB)  TX bytes:20740 (20.2 KiB)

  wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ef:c0:05:a9  
        inet6 addr: fe80::475a:4576:d95:13f4/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

NOTE: I did attempt to modify the network interfaces file to **replace 'manual' with 'dhcp'** and to **add 'auto wlan0'** like I used to but that didn't fix things at all.

But **eth0 and wired connections to my modem work** fine with SSH and all.

Comment: Did you see any errors in the output of `dmesg` ?

Comment: @ShreyasMurali: good call. the `dmesg` show a warning like `[   83.979381] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_tx_sta_fifo_read_completed: Warning - TX status read failed -71` repeated 100+ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out a distro upgrade solved my issue. I just followed the steps in the '**[upgrading and updating](http://oursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome)**' section of the documentation.

After this, the dongle worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

## Part 1 - Clarifying the terminology

I like to visualize the different parts like so

```
[kernel] <=> [device driver] <=> [firmware] <=> [physical device]
```

sometimes a device might not require a specialized firmware and the driver can directly communicate with the physical device.

here are some common commands and the o/p they produce:

`uname -a` : gives you the kernel version (4.4.13-v7+ in your case)

`cat /etc/os-release` : gives you the friendly OS version (e.g raspbian/wheezy or raspbian/jessie)

`apt list --installed *firm*` : gives you the list of all packages that have a the word **firm** in their names

`modinfo rt2800usb` : gives you the version details of the driver loaded for the ralink usb wifi dongle

for completeness sake, i will add `lsmod` : gives you the list of drivers (kernel modules) that are currently loaded

In your case it appears both the kernel and the driver (`rt2800usb`) have been updated successfully.

## Part 2 - Diagnosing  the problem

Searching for `rt2800usb_tx_sta_fifo_read_completed` in the linux source code cross reference
I found it located [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800usb.c#L150).

Clicking the identifier took me to a page that lists all the references and one such reference is the method, 
`rt2x00usb_register_read_async` which is located [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00usb.c#L183).

The method `rt2800usb_tx_sta_fifo_read_completed` has been passed in as a callback to be executed when the read completes (successfully or not)

```
183 void rt2x00usb_register_read_async(struct rt2x00_dev *rt2x00dev,
184                                    const unsigned int offset,
185                                    bool (*callback)(struct rt2x00_dev*, int, u32))
186 {
187         struct usb_device *usb_dev = to_usb_device_intf(rt2x00dev->dev);
188         struct urb *urb;
189         struct rt2x00_async_read_data *rd;
190 
191         rd = kmalloc(sizeof(*rd), GFP_ATOMIC);
192         if (!rd)
193                 return;
194 
195         urb = usb_alloc_urb(0, GFP_ATOMIC);
196         if (!urb) {
197                 kfree(rd);
198                 return;
199         }
200 
201         rd->rt2x00dev = rt2x00dev;
202         rd->callback = callback;
203         rd->cr.bRequestType = USB_VENDOR_REQUEST_IN;
204         rd->cr.bRequest = USB_MULTI_READ;
205         rd->cr.wValue = 0;
206         rd->cr.wIndex = cpu_to_le16(offset);
207         rd->cr.wLength = cpu_to_le16(sizeof(u32));
208 
209         usb_fill_control_urb(urb, usb_dev, usb_rcvctrlpipe(usb_dev, 0),
210                              (unsigned char *)(&rd->cr), &rd->reg, sizeof(rd->reg),
211                              rt2x00usb_register_read_async_cb, rd);
212         usb_anchor_urb(urb, rt2x00dev->anchor);
213         if (usb_submit_urb(urb, GFP_ATOMIC) < 0) {
214                 usb_unanchor_urb(urb);
215                 kfree(rd);
216         }
217         usb_free_urb(urb);
218 }
```

from the above definition it appears the USB read call is failing with error code -71 and thats what is getting printed in dmesg

so WTH does-71 mean ? Again googling around, I found a number of posts such as

- [this](https://urukrama.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/usb-drive-not-recognised-error-71/) which claims is a problem with `usbcore` and also suggests a fix like so

> An internet search indicated this is not an uncommon problem, and usbcore, which is compiled as a module in Hardy’s kernel, seems to be the culprit. Plenty of suggestions were offered online (including recompiling the kernel) but most of them did not help me at all.
>   Finally, I found something on an old mailing list that solved the problem. All I needed to do was add the following line to /etc/modprobe.d/options:
>         `options usbcore use_both_schemes=y`
>   (If you are curious as to why this solved the problem, please read [this clear explanation](http://www.spinics.net/lists/usb/msg02644.html).)

- [this](https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error) which claims it is current consumption related.

And found a few more like those.

Since you have mentioned the device used to work prior to updating, I m inclined to think update might have broken compatiblity 
with the firmware package (firmware-ralink) installed which is showing up with different error messages.

If you can check the version of the firmware installed by running `apt list --installed firmware-ralink` 
and share the details, it might help identifying/narrow down the problem.

You could also try updating the firmware package like so `apt-get install --only-upgrade firmware-ralink` and checking it it makes a difference.

---

You could also try the following to check if it actually power supply related

- use a 5V, 2A+ power supply
- disconnect all unnecessary usb devices (keyboard/mouse/hub/flash drive etc) and use ssh via ethernet to login

Comment: It seems modprobe does not have an option file. Also I have the latest firmware-ralink version.

I also only had the WiFi Usb dongle plugged in while SSH-ing into the Pi via Ethernet linked to a modem. Just for checks, I changed the power adaptor to the one my friend uses, to no avail.

`apt list --installed firmware-ralink` gives `firmware-ralink/stable,now 0.43+rpi5 all [installed]` and the upgrade command outputs `firmware-ralink is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem, it turned out that the usb cable(s) between the pc and the usbwifi, were simply too long to provide proper power/voltage, so if you're using cable extensions,  dont let them be too long and check for faulty ones